# Tomcat SSL Implementation not showing the Certificate chain in the browser

Tags: tomcat, ssl, browser, https, ssl-certificate

I'm implementing SSL in tomcat i.e. https and have done the below steps -
1)Generated Keystore & CSR using java keytool
2)Got it signed by CA autority.
3)Imported the signed,CA Root & intermediate certificate into the keystore.
4)Updated the server.xml in tomcat to use this keystore along with the password

Actually I've followed all the steps as mentioned in the tomcat tutorial but certificate chain is not visible in browser.

When I hit the tomcat with https url, the brower is showing certificate error and not showing the certificate chain instead just showing the private key. How to resolve this?

Thanks in advance! Please advise

Comment: You imported the certificates how exactly?

Answer (score -5):

Please use the below link for all the SSL configuration details under Tomcat

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Please see if your missing any steps.

Comment: Out of date link-only answer, and OP states he is already using the Tomcat tutorial.